# Cannot access samba share on windows but on mac os it works

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba, smb

I am sharing a directory on a ubuntu server over samba. When I mount the samba share with mac os x then it works perfectly fine. However, when I mount the samba share on windows and I enter the exact credentials as before, I get the error message:

> \172.20.1.2\share is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than on user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

I have totally no idea what went wrong. When I enter the credentials on windows I even excluded the domain by entering the username as \admin . Does anyone know what the problem is or what I can check to get further details about what the actual problem is?

Comment: This question is more suitable for [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 2):

The problem that somehow the windows machine already "cached" an old credential. After restarting the machine it works fine.